# Angular dependancy not loading

Tags: javascript, angularjs

The title may be deceiving, but I do not know what is going on here. Here is my controller setup:

```
angular.module('myApp.controllers', [])
.controller('AboutCtrl', ['$scope', 'About', function ($scope, About) {
    $scope.about = About.query();
}])
```

I am getting the angular error: http://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/unpr?p0=AboutProvider%20%3C-%20About.

I have this module:

```
angular.module('myApp.restServices', ['ngResource'])
    .factory('About', ['$resource',
        function ($resource) {
            return $resource(service.about, {});
        }])
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

The answer was pretty simple, when declaring the myApp module, I need to inject the dependancy:

```
angular.module('myApp', [
    'ngTouch',
    'ngRoute',
    'ngAnimate',
    'myApp.controllers',
    'myApp. restServices'
]).
```